# freetextbox is not loading properly

Tags: asp.net, freetext, freetextbox

I have 28 `freetexboxes` on my ASP.NET 4.5 web form and the 29th freetexbox does not load properly. The 29th `freetextbox` doesn't have color or border. Can someone tell me how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue but it resolved for me by changing the css file.

As far as I understand the FreeTextBox is developed using the table. I had commented the margin-top: and padding element from main css file used in website. After commenting out. It worked as expected.